# vite Error when evaluating SSR module: failed to import tailwind.config.cjs - ReferenceError: module not defined + astro unable to load config.mjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, astrojs

been trying to solve the following problems searching the net for hours, but cant find a solution for it.
Can anybody help me with a hint?

I am using node.js and
these:
"dependencies": {
"@astrojs/image": "^0.17.2",
"@astrojs/tailwind": "^4.0.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
"astro": "^2.9.1",
"composer": "^4.1.0",
"cors": "2.8.5",
"flaschenpost": "^5.1.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"php": "^1.0.2",
"sharp": "^0.32.1",
"uuid": "^9.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"astro-icon": "^0.8.1",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"

It came up, when I tried to put in the backend folder with some js for my contact form. (the backend with the js and stuff works all fine!)

```
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /tailwind.config.cjs:
|- ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at C:\Users\maxim\Website\tailwind.config.cjs:5:1
    at async instantiateModule (file:...)
```

```
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module C:\Users\maxim\Website\astro.config.mjs: failed to import "/tailwind.config.cjs"
|- ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at C:\Users\maxim\Website\tailwind.config.cjs:5:1
    at async instantiateModule (file:....)
```

```
[astro] Unable to load C:...\astro.config.mjs      

 error   module is not defined
  File:
    C:\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-e8f070e8.js:54405:9
  Code:
    54404 |             `\n//# sourceURL=${mod.id}${sourceMapSuffix}`);      
    > 54405 |         await initModule (context.global, ssrModule, ssrImportMeta, ssrImport, ssrDynamicImport, ssrExportAll);
            |         ^
      54406 |     }
      54408 |         mod.ssrError = e;
  Stacktrace:
ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at C:\tailwind.config.cjs:5:1
    at async instantiateModule (file:/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:54405:9)
```

- I tried to change the astro.config with plugins and stuff... nothing changed
- I double checked the astro.config with the config from astro docs
- I looked through Stack, Lightrun, github, but found nothing

I didnt change anything in astro.config or tailwind.config so why is that happening?